# Is AR(p) strictly stationar?

Tags: statistics, random-variables

Good evening.

Is it true that model AR(p) is a strictly stacionar random sequence? Model AR(p) is given by $X_{t} = \varphi_{1} X_{t-1} + \ldots + \varphi_{p} X_{t-p} + Y_{t}$ where $\{Y_{t}\}_{t \in {Z}}$ is white noise and strict stacionarity means that all finite-dimensional distributions are invariant with respect to shift. If so, can you prove it?